# Testing Timbre log outputs with Midje

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, midje, timbre

I am using [Timbre](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre) as a logging library but I am having issues testing it with [Midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje). I've got the following method and all I'm trying to do is asserting that `Will be printed` is printed.

```
(defn init [level]
    (timbre/merge-config! {:output-fn my-output-fn})
    (timbre/set-level! level)
    (timbre/info "Will be printed")
    (timbre/debug "Won't be printed"))
```

By wrapping `(timbre/default-output-fn)` around a function of my own `my-output-fn`, I am able to assert that only 1 out of 2 logs are printed, which is true:

```
(fact "print info but not debug"
    (core/init :info) => nil
    (provided
        (core/my-output-fn anything) => irrelevant :times 1))
```

However I would like to make sure that the message being printed is `Will be printed`. I can't find any way of doing this, what would you do?

I am doing experiments in the following project https://github.com/stephanebruckert/timbre-midje

Comment: While I am not familiar with midge, have you looked at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310619/clojure-configure-timbre-logging/32340732#32340732

Comment: Yes, and we can see that the answer got around the problem by using a comment: `(trace "Hello, Timbre! trace")  ; will not be logged, below current log-level`. That's what I want to automate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ErwinRooijakkers' idea worked but [@ptaoussanis on Github](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/issues/197) has a good reason not to do it.

> Please note that [`timbre/vargs->margs`](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/issues/197) is private, and an implementation
>   detail. Its behaviour can change at any time without notice, would
>   strongly recommend not depending on it in any way.
>
> It'd be possible to use a custom appender that sends output somewhere that are handy for your tests to analyse. You could setup these appenders as part of your test setup, and/or use something like `timbre/with-config` for the appropriate test calls.

So we can add an appender that passes the parameters to check (`level` `message`) to a stub.

*core.clj*

```
(defn init
  ([level]
    (init level {}))
  ([level config]
    (timbre/merge-config! config)
    (timbre/set-level! level)
    (timbre/info "will be printed")
    (timbre/debug "won't be printed")))
```

---

*core_test.clj*

```
(:require [timbre-midje.core :as core]
          [midje.sweet :refer :all]))

(defn log-stub [level message])

(def log-stub-appender
  {:appenders
    {:test-appender
      {:enabled? true
       :fn (fn [data] (log-stub (:level data) (:vargs data)))}}})

(fact "print info but not debug"
  (core/init :info log-stub-appender) => nil
  (provided
    (log-stub :info ["will be printed"]) => irrelevant :times 1
    (log-stub :debug ["won't be printed"]) => irrelevant :times 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to validate the input of a function using Midje's [`as-checker` prerequisite](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Checkers-within-prerequisites).

When you print the `data` that come into `timbre/default-output-fn` (I discovered this via your `output-fn`) you see it has the following structure:

> {:hash_ #delay[{:status :pending, :val nil} 0x5ed805b1], :instant #inst "2016-10-14T17:07:16.779-00:00", :config {:level :info, ....

So the log-level is available in `data`. With `as-checker` the `log level` can be validated as follows:

```
(fact "print info but not debug"
      (core/init :info) => nil
      (provided
       (timbre/default-output-fn anything ; opts is first argument
                                 (as-checker (fn [data]
                                               (= (-> data :config :level) ; get log level
                                                  :info))))     ; validate that it is info
       => anything :times 1)
      (provided
       (timbre/default-output-fn anything
                                 (as-checker (fn [data]
                                               (= (-> data :config :level)
                                                  :debug))))
       => anything :times 0))
```

Now, you wanted to check the content of the message. Not only the log level.

The actual message is not available in the `opts` or `data` passed toward `default-output-fn`. Looking around in the the Timbre code I saw it is available in a private function `vargs->margs` that takes an `?err`, a `msg-type` and `vargs`. The `vargs` contain the message (in your case what comes in is for example `:auto :p ["The message"])`.

Via the `as-checker` approach the messages can be validated follows:

```
(fact "print Will be printed, not Won't be printed"
      (core/init :info) => nil
      (provided
       (#'timbre/vargs->margs anything anything ["Will be printed"]) => {} :times 1)
      (provided
       (#'timbre/vargs->margs anything anything ["Won't be printed"]) => {} :times 0) )
```

Note that `vargs->margs` has to return a map, otherwise Timbre throws an exception in a later function.

This way it is validated that "Will be printed" is printed once, and "Won't be printed" is never printed.

Comment: Thanks! There might be a simpler way though. Code is here: https://github.com/erooijak/timbre-midje.

Comment: I see. Note that the log level checking did not work at first, but does after the edit. Thanks for the problem.